# How can I link OptionMenu's after reading from an Excelfile?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to build a GUI that can open en read Excel files. I already have Radiobuttons that each link to a different folder. In this folder, multiple files can be selected. Then two OptionMenu's appear, one that reads the sheets of the excel and one that reads the columns of the Excel. This is where I get stuck. I can't seem to link these two OptionMenu's to each other. This is my code so far:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
global data, sheets, sheetsList

class filedialogexample(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.favorite = tkinter.StringVar()        

        tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text = "Browse 1", variable = self.favorite, 
            command=self.askopenfilename, value="C:\\Users\\Documents\\Python Scripts"
            ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='w')  

    def askopenfilename(self):       
        self.variable = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.variable.set("Sensors")
        self.variable2 = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.variable2.set("Signals")        
        filenames = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir=self.favorite.get())
        if filenames:
            root.tk.splitlist(filenames)
            for file in filenames:
                data = pd.ExcelFile(file)               
                sheets = pd.read_excel(file)
                sheetsList = {data:[sheets]}
                tab=tkinter.OptionMenu(self, self.variable,    
                              *data.sheet_names, command = self._selectSignal
                                  ).grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2)                                                         

                column=tkinter.OptionMenu(self, self.variable2,  
                              *list(sheets) 
                                     ).grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2)   


    def _selectSignal(self, choice):
        columns = sheetsList[self.variable.get()]
        column.setitems(columns)

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    filedialogexample(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

The error that I get is:

```
NameError: name 'sheetsList' is not defined
```

But if I put the _selectSignal in the same line as if filenames, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'filedialogexample' object has no attribute '_selectSignal'
```

I don't know how to fix this. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this question?

Comment: @xmcp, I rewrote the question to make it shorter and clearer. It was a bit of a mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `global` statements to every methods will (probably) solve the problem.

p.s. You might have some misunderstandings about the global statement. Here is the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement).

Comment: Thanks, that helped!